# Update variable passed to directive dynamically through attrs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

We get value of variable through parse but how can i update that variable back ,which is passed to directive through attr dynamically?

```
some editor,
edit.type="dir"
edit.attr.myattr="scopeVar"

dir
scope: { myattr: '='}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you are having issues?